# How to display Toast notification popup as modal dialog?

Tags: toastr

I want to show to toastr.js notification as modal dialog so that once the toast notification is displayed on the screen, the end user cannot perform any kind of operations on the screen. The behavior should be similar to the bootstrap modal pop dialog.

Can any one guide me how to achieve the behavior with toastr.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the goal of toastr.

However, if you modify the CSS of the toast you will be able to make a toast take up the entirety of the screen.